# WP Как создать страницу написания отзыва для поста?

Tags: wordpress

Имеется страница поста кастомного типа. `post_type => 'company'` Что бы не захламлять страницу данного поста дизайнер нарисовал страницу на которой зарегистрированный пользователь может написать про этот продукт. Выглядит она вот так.
[image: Страница оставить отзыв]
Вопрос, как привязать данную страницу со страницей этого продукта/компании?
Взята идея данной страницы [вот с этой темы](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/vanno-consumers-reviews-and-rating-directory/full_screen_preview/22805107).
Подскажите, куда копать...?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/note/otdelnaya-stranitsa-dlya-kommentariev-zapisi